# Meaning of 何もなし

Tags: grammar, particles

> ひっさびさに会えるってのに、何もナシじゃつまんねーだろ (Persona 5 Scramble)

I can't seem to wrap my head around the 何もなし. Specifically how the 何も fits with the なし and the adjective being in the negative form at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

何もナシ means "(there is) nothing at all".

- 何も is a **negative polarity item**, which is always followed by a negation (ない, ぬ, ず, ...). Please see: [The reason for using 何も+negative, but 何でも+positive](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1565/5010)
- This なし is a classic version of ない, but it is still used when brevity is important. Please see: [What form is あり?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/35942/5010)

なし on its own means "there is not", but 何も strengthens the meaning ("there is nothing at all").