# Is there a particle dropped in the sentence お届け物いたします?

Tags: particles

In the sign in the movie "Kiki's Delivery Service" it says お届け物いたします.
In this case is the particle を or が dropped due to informal spoken language?
Is the tacit が the person offering the delivery service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> お届け物（を）いたします。

を is dropped here.

In signboards / [看板]{かんばん} (and traffic signs /[標識]{ひょうしき} too), case particles such as が, を are often omitted.

Examples:

> 配達**を**承ります → 配達承ります
> 裾上げ・寸法直し**を**致します → 裾上げ・寸法直し致します
> 内職**を**請け負います → 内職請け負います
> マスク**を**入荷しました → マスク入荷しました
> ヱビスビール**が**あります → ヱビスビールあります

[image]

[image]

[image]

Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/35945/9831

Answer (score 0):

Hello and pardon my poor English.

No. It didn't drop anything.

> ご／お＋Verbます(stem) / Noun verb (勉強　etc.) ＋いたします／します

is a grammar for honorifics speech. The most polite way of how you can say something.

it means "to do"